# Anova or Bonferroni correction needed?

Tags: anova, bonferroni

I've read a bit when it is appropriate to use Anova/Bonferroni correction over multiple t-tests but I am not sure if it applies to my data. I am extracting audio features from themed Spotify playlists for each track and want to compare if selected features (think tempo, danceability etc...) are significantly different for the themes (a workout playlist vs. a studying playlist vs. a party playlist for example). So a comparison of danceability of group a vs danceability of group b etc...

I believe it is necessary since the features were derived from the same song so they are dependent in this way. And I learned when I need to use Bonferroni I can also just use an ANOVA instead.

Comment: There are many methods that can be used alongside ANOVA for multiple comparison correction, such as Bonferroni, Tukey, Scheffe etc., Bonferroni having low statistical power. I don't quite understand your situation but I'm just responding to your last statement

Comment: My initial idea was to use multiple t-tests to compare each feature between different groups. Regarding the correction, thanks. I remember hearing about different methods like Tukey indeed. I just want to know if I need to do such a correction or if it's not necessary in my case.

Comment: As you make more inferences your type I error simply increases, so it's basically a question of whether you're doing multiple comparisons or not. Bonferroni for instance basically shrinks your initial alpha so that after each of your comparison it inflates back up to where you wanted it in the first place. But I think what you might be getting at is you can use ANOVA to test the null hypothesis that all means are equal, and you may find at least one is statistically different from the others. Then to test which ones are different you need to use multiple comparisons corrections.

Comment: The issue of dependence is not relevant as to *whether* you should apply multiple comparison corrections. However, if you do wish to apply such corrections, then dependence becomes important when considering *how* to apply them.